# Draw 2D Line on 3D cube in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

Want to create small example in unity 3d where in lines (2D either of plan XY,XZ etc.) will be drawn on 3D cube.
Here is my intention expected [3D cube with 2D lines on front wall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqwg2.jpg)

As per img Cube front face wall have 2D lines sticking to Z=0. Similarly 2D line can be belong to anywhere- e.g. inside cube or wall of cube

I'm trying to achieve this in Unity. Currently i'm hardcoding it, but its intended to be dynamic - line can be drawn on any face/plan from script given line coordinates.

I could
[Achieved this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLtII.jpg)

As per image it - LineRenderer used with 2 points, but I didn't understand why its not 2D line its rectangle?

Line should stick to same place even after rotating cube - using script i could redraw line on transform operation. But i'm thinking is there any better way 1s drawn on cube it sticks not need to redraw line on every transform (scale/position/rotation)?

Can any 1 help me how do i achieve

Answer (score 1):

> As per image it - LineRenderer used with 2 points, but I didn't
>   understand why its not 2D line its rectangle?

It's not rectangle. It looks like rectangle because the **width** of your `LineRenderer` is too high. That's the problem. Reduce the **width** and it should now look like a line. When I say width, I mean the [`LineRenderer.startWidth`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer-startWidth.html) and [`LineRenderer.endWidth`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer-endWidth.html) variables. 
Also, make sure to use the-same value for these two variables.

Note:

*The easiest way to figure out which width is good for what you are doing is to click Play, select your `LineRenderer` GameObject, then modify it. When you like the value, then click Stop then plug that good value to your code.*

Comment: Don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) answer if your problem is solved.

Comment: I missed 1 point just updated question. how can it achieve to stick line even after transform operations?

Comment: This is totally another problem. Also, without your code, it is not possible to help you with this one. Can you create a new question with your code then show what the problem in your new question is?